# How update on save indexing works in magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise, indexing, magento-1.14

In enterprise 1.14 version of Magento, we are using flat tables and reindexing is achieved by cron job and from command line i.e  php indexer.php reindexall. But when I am trying the "update on save" option for reindexing, indexing process is not working when a product is saved. Why it is so? Which methods are responsible for the update on save indexing process and how I can debug this.

Thanks

Comment: I have also checked logs, nothing found in system/exception log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update on Save is handled by an observer. Check out this class: `Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Observer_Category_Product`

Below I've listed the methods you will want to take a look at, and after each method I have listed the events that those methods are attached to.

- `processProductSaveEvent`

  - `enterprise_product_flat`
  - `enterprise_catalog_category_product`
  - `enterprise_product_price`
- `processUpdateWebsiteForProduct`

  - `enterprise_catalog_category_product_website`
- `processCategorySaveEvent`

  - `enterprise_category_flat`
  - `enterprise_catalog_category_product`
  - `enterprise_catalog_category_product`

Hopefully this is enough to help you debug the issue!

Comment: Can I re-index single product programmatically ?